# I got same store data from different client reuqest , nuxt / nodejs / vuex / aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I try to build up a ssr project.
So I use store in asyncData function as follow

```
async asyncData({ store, params, req }) {
  if(process.server){
    store.dispatch(...)
    store.commit(...)
    return {...}
  }
}
```

It works great in client dev environment, it creates new store with new axios client for every
request for server side render.
But once I put it to lab, a container build up on aws, it goes wired.
Request and session were different, but they shared the same store, and axios instance.
So that make my data mess up.

lib:
"nuxt": "^2.12.2",
"axios": "^0.19.2",

========================= update 1 =========================

I got first point, once I build up and run locally, it ran in same result.
before script:

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=development backpack"
```

now script:

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production nuxt build"
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production backpack build"
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production node build/main.js"
```

Comment: you dont need `if(process.server)` because `asyncData` is always on server side

Comment: It does run in client as well, but that's not the point to cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem is how I defined for store module.

```
    // won't share state
    const state = {}
    export default {
      state: () => { return { ...state } }
    }
    // share state
    const state = {}
    export default {
      state:() => state
    }
```